# "Something went wrong", error in Visual Studio Community

Tags: windows, visual-studio, ide

I have searched all over the Internet, every answer related to this topic in StackOverFlow, but nowhere could I find an answer to this specific problem, and thus I felt the need to make a thread for this.

So when I open the **vs_community.exe** downloaded from the official site, it shows a **getting started** message, and after that this screen shows up.

[Problem Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUGBQ.png)

As far as I have read around websites, you are typically shown a screen where you are supposed to choose the components, languages etc. But in my case, this shows up, with the setup being apparently *paused*?
And when I try to click on the resume button of that unconfigured setup...
[Problem Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suIeU.png)

As I said earlier, I didn't find any answers anywhere, so I am confused at this point. What might be the cause of this, and is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Try running the installer in a clean system (e.g. in a [Windows Sandbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-overview)). If the issue persists then this could indicate a hardware issue. If the problem goes away then there is probably something wrong with your system configuration.

Comment: @IInspectable Surprisingly, installing the Pro version or the Enterprise version does not show any errors, but they are limited trial versions so no. I will try Windows Sandbox, but I feel too that it is a hardware issue.

Comment: If you can install the Pro Edition without issues then this does *not* indicate a hardware issue. The Community Edition is identical with the Pro Edition (modulo licensing terms) after all.